# Printing the biggest int from text file from and give the line this int is located in

Tags: python-3.x, text, int, text-files

I have a text file:

```
Jan Jansen heeft kaartnummer: 325255
Erik Materus heeft kaartnummer: 334343
Ali Ahson heeft kaartnummer: 235434
Eva Versteeg heeft kaartnummer: 645345
Jan de Wilde heeft kaartnummer: 534545
Henk de Vrie heeft kaartnummer: 345355
```

I need to print three things: the biggest int value, the number of lines and the line the biggest int is located in. I have done the first two, but I have no idea how to print the line the biggest int is located in. I hope you guys can help me.

This is what I got so far:

```
import re

num_lines = sum(1 for line in open("Kaartnummers.txt"))
print(num_lines)

int = open("Kaartnummers.txt", "r")

file = open("Kaartnummers.txt", "r")

file = file.read()

numbers = re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", file)

print(numbers)

numbers.sort()
print("The b"numbers[-1])
```

I know its very messy but I'm very new to coding and so I'm not very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps... A part of it uses python 3.6, but you can omit it it you have a file ready. The last few lines answer your immediate question.

```
import csv
from pathlib import Path


doc = """Jan Jansen heeft kaartnummer: 325255
Erik Materus heeft kaartnummer: 334343
Ali Ahson heeft kaartnummer: 235434
Eva Versteeg heeft kaartnummer: 645345
Jan de Wilde heeft kaartnummer: 534545
Henk de Vrie heeft kaartnummer: 345355"""

# recreating your file with data, python 3.6 
# skip this line if you have the file already
Path("mydata.csv").write_text(doc)

with open("mydata.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    rows = [row for row in reader]

# now you have your data inside interpreter as list of strings  
print(rows)    

# this seems to be common string in all the lines 
sep = " heeft kaartnummer: "

# lets seperate name and values to be bale to play with them
rows2 = [row[0].split(sep) for row in rows] 
print(rows2)

# lets associate the kaartnummer with a name in a dictionary
knum_dict = {int(num):name for name, num in rows2}  
print(knum_dict)


#I need to print three things: 
#    the biggest int value, 
#    the number of lines 
#    and the line the biggest int is located in.

print()
print("Total number of lines:", len(rows))
max_num = max(knum_dict.keys())
print()
print("Biggest int:", max_num)
print("The biggest int is found for:", knum_dict[max_num])

#now back to your original quection - 
#and the line the biggest int is located in
for i, row in enumerate(rows2):
    if int(row[1]) == max_num:
        # 
        print("The biggest int is found in line:", i+1)
        print("(first line number is 1)"
```